# Adding padding on the container using Zurb Ink

Tags: css

I am attempting to add padding either side of an email so that it's consistent through the whole mailer, but it seems to be lop sided for some reason. I want a 40px gutter either side of each row, but can't seem to achieve it.

**HTML**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ink.css"> <!-- For testing only -->

    <style type="text/css">

      /* Ink styles go here in production */

    </style>
    <style type="text/css">

    .email-container {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      padding: 0 40px !important;
    }

      .sub-columns {
        padding: 15px !important;
      }

      .row-highlight {
        background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
      }

      .wrapper {
        padding-top: 0 !important;
      }
      .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .product {
        padding-left: 30px !important;
      }

      .bold-row td {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .row-secondary {
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }

      .align-right {
        text-align: right;
      }

      .invoice a,
      .invoice a:visited,
      .social a,
      .social a:visited {
        color: #c40162 !important;
        font-size: 13px !important;
        text-decoration: underline !important;
      }

      .nav,
      .nav a {
        color: #757575 !important;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      .logo {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      .social {
        background-color: #e8e8e8!important;
        color: #4d4d4d !important;
        padding-top: 20px !important;
      }

      .title {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
        border-left: 0 !important;
        border-right: 0 !important;
        border-top: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 30px 0 !important;
      }

      .footer {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-left: 0 !important;
        border-right: 0 !important;
        border-top: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
        border-bottom: 0;
        color: #171717;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 20px 0 !important;
      }
      .footer a {
        color: #c40162 !important;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      .content {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #171717;
        line-height: 20px;
      }

      .content-title {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 15px !important;
      }

      .table-border-bottom {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
      }

      .table-border-top {
        border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
      }

      .no-bottom-padding {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      }

      .spacer {
        padding: 20px 0 0 0 !important;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background:#ddd">
    <table class="body" style="background:#ddd">
      <tr>
        <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" >
          <center>

            <table class="email-container" style="background:#fff">
              <tr>
                <td>

                  <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="wrapper last">
                        <table class="twelve columns">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="text-pad spacer"></td>               
                            <td class="expander"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <table class="row">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                          <table class="twelve columns nav">
                            <tr>
                              <!-- Logo -->
                              <td class="five sub-columns logo"><img height="50" width="50" src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=LCN"></td>
                              <!-- Logo End -->

                              <!-- Nav Items-->
                              <td class="two sub-columns nav"><a href="#">Support</a></td>
                              <td class="two sub-columns nav"><a href="#">Contact</a></td>
                              <td class="two sub-columns nav last"><a href="#">Login</a></td>
                              <!-- Nav items End -->
                              <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="row">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                          <table class="twelve columns">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="text-pad spacer">               
                              <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="row">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                          <table class="eleven columns">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="center text-pad title">Thank you for your order</td>
                              <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="row">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                          <table class="twelve columns">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="text-pad">               
                                <h5>Hi %%name%%,</h5>
                                <p class="lead">Thank you for your order.</p>
                              </td>
                              <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="row">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                          <table class="twelve columns">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="text-pad">
                                  <p>&#169; 2015</p>
                              </td>
                              <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                <!-- container end below -->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**
 Standard Zurb CSS

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pardigan/L5nvc6rn/1/

Comment: do you have this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure - https://jsfiddle.net/pardigan/L5nvc6rn/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L5nvc6rn/2/ not sure if you want it on the white or padding all around so you see some grey

Comment: Thanks, that's got me on the right track. Always overlook the simple styles!!

Comment: I will place it in as an answer then if thats what you were looking for

Comment: For emails, you can always try using a `border` in your CSS or inline styles that act as padding. That way you'll get better support in Outlook. Just match the border color with the background. It may require more nesting, and isn't related directly to Zurb Ink (but can be used in any email).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/L5nvc6rn/2/

If you place padding on the containing TD then it will give you the padding that you might need for example:

```
<td style="padding:40px;">
```